# Feed items field from Feed node

Tags: 7, entities, feeds

I'm looking for a way to make Feed items inherit a field value from its parent Feed importer node during the import. The idea is to later use this field value in views filter. In my case this field contains the nid value of referenced node that should be the same for Feed importer node and all of its feed items, and different for other importers and their feed items.

What I have found a quiet similar issue:
http://www.zivtech.com/blog/feed-feeds-importing-referenced-rss-data

but unfortunately I'm not very good at coding and cant find out the reason why this solution doesnt work in my case. Maybe there is a way to do this through views relationships or any other module like Rules or Node Hierarchy?

I also found an module for Drupal 6 that might do this kind of stuff but it wont work for Drupal 7 and Feeds module: [FeedAPI Field Inherit](http://drupal.org/project/feedapi_field_inherit)

If some one has an advice for this issue please help. Thanks!

Comment: Solved by rewriting fields in Rules.

Answer (score 3):

The node ID of the parent feed node should be attached to each child feed-item node. Using this in either the template file, or within Views, you can get to the data you require.

For example :

In a Views listing. Add a relationship to the parent feed.
Add a new field for content title - but attach it to the relationship - this gives the parent title. Same applies for any other fields you may have added to the parent.

In template.php -- do a `node_load($node->PARENT URL REFERENCE GOES HERE)` this will give you access to all the variables on the parent node. If this sounds alien to you then you probably don't need it.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Feeds 7.x-2.0-alpha5, and its standard *Node processor* allows you to map fields from parent *Feed* node to children *Feed Item* nodes. Have a look under *Mapping* link in for *Node processor*. (Btw, if you're using standard importer, you would need to *override* it first and then *edit* to get to its settings.